# Using find on an array of strings

Tags: javascript

I have data similiar to this

```
const data = [
  'one',
  [
    {id: 1, value: 'A'},
    {id: 2, value: 'B'}
  ],
  'two',
  [
    {id: 3, value: 'C'},
    {id: 4, value: 'D'}
  ],
  'three',
  [
    {id: 5, value: 'E'},
    {id: 6, value: 'F'}
  ],
]
```

just looking for a way to find the array for a given "key"  for example find the array after the element 'two'

obviously
`const myArray = data['two']` does not work

I am currently solving with the following.

```
let myResult = [];
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
 if (data[i] === 'two')
  myResult = data[i + 1];
}

console.log(myResult);
```

but there must be a more concise way.

https://jsfiddle.net/yjb7hfk4/

Comment: Why are you using this horrible format? Make it an object whose keys are the strings and values are the nested arrays of objects.

Comment: Use `indexOf()` to get the index of the string. Then add 1 to get the index of the corresponding array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `indexOf()` to find the index of the string, then add 1 to get the result.

```js
const data = [
  'one', [
   {id: 1, value: 'A'},
   {id: 2, value: 'B'}
   ],
   'two', [
      {id: 3, value: 'C'},
      {id: 4, value: 'D'}
   ],
    'three', [
      {id: 5, value: 'E'},
      {id: 6, value: 'F'}
   ],
]

let index = data.indexOf("two");
let myResult;
if (index != -1) {
  myResult = data[index+1];
  console.log(myResult);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using indexOf in a one-liner

```
      const myArray = data[data.indexOf("two") + 1]
```

Comment: @BryanDellinger ... this answer should not be considered the accepted one (nor should it be upvoted) for it is not fail safe ... in case nothing was found (return value of `-1`) the result always would be the array's first item (index of `0`) which is not the expected result.

Comment: I agree, should have specified that, unless this is an expected result